# How to get default browser in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add wallpaper in chrome tabs , But I checked it is not possible to access newtab through `content script`. Only solution is to do override whole page, is it possible to get user default browser and using that we can make a search bar where user can search through default one

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "pageToOverride": "myPage.html"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: There's no API to get user's search engine so you'll have to show a selector so that the user can switch it.

Comment: @wOxxOm ohk thanks, but how to make search then and navigate to user selected search engine?

Comment: Just like you would do it in any other html page: a `form` with an `input` element (https://puu.sh/Esq08/613271f330.png) or using javascript.

Comment: @wOxxOm ohk, one more thing is it safe to use firebase directly from frontend because it actually exposes the credentials, anyone can retrieve code from .crx file ?

Comment: Everyone can retrieve it, yes, but whether it's "safe" or not is for you to decide :-)